# How to set value from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set value from one page to another.
let's say I have page called a.html, and page b.html and b.html has a text input.

Is it possible to set text in that input from a.html without make any editing in code to b.html, it should be on runtime?
I could get the text value from b.html to a.html with `.load()` but I don't know how to set value from one to another.

Answer (score 1):

There is few ways you can pass the information from one page to another

1. QueryString
2. Cookies
3. Local/Session Storage

You can choose anyone of these option and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Cookies** to save data and get in other page.
**To set cookie:**
document.cookie = "username='Foobar'";

**To get Cookie:**
var x = document.cookie;